# How to use MS SQL as database for Android Studio

Tags: android, sql, visual-studio

I want to use MS SQL Server 2008 as Main Database for my Android Studio is there any way to Connect Android Studio With MS SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Can you?  Yes.  Should you?  Not directly.  If you connect to a database directly in your app, that means you put your password in your app.  This means you have 0 security, and if your app has any value at all it will be hacked.  Use a webservice instead, so the password never needs to leave your servers.  And that webservice can connect to whatever it wants as a db, the android app should neither know nor care.

Comment: How do i make a service and use that service in android studio??

Comment: How to write a webservice is way too broad.  You need to do some research on it.